# A poker card game in C. Please explain suits[4][9], and faces[13][6]?

Tags: c, arrays, poker

So I have a sample code to create a deck of card for a mini poker game in [c](/questions/tagged/c). But I do not understand how the suits and faces are determined. Why do these arrays have 2 dimensions? I know that `[9]` and `[6]` are the columns of the array, but I do not understand the purpose of them.

```
char suits[4][9]= {"Hearts","Diamonds","Clubs","Spades"};   
char faces[13][6]= {"Ace","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9", "10","Jack",
                "Queen","King"};
```

Comment: 9 and 6 are just the (maximum) string sizes (allowing +1 for the string terminator). 4 and 13 are the numbers of suits and ranks. May I recommend choosing something from [this list of good books on C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/562303/253056) ?

Comment: Think about what the type of `"Hearts"` is vs what is the declared type of elements of `suits`?

Comment: Personally, I would have just `const char *suits[] = {....};` and eliminated the chance of someone entering in too-small a value for the inferior dimension. That, and I see little reason anyone would need to *modify* those strings during the runtime of the program.

Comment: @Paul R Ahh! I thought that they were columns for the array for some reason. How silly! Thanks a lot, this make a lot more sense now.

Comment: Well they sort of *are* columns, if you think of each string as a row, and the characters within each as having a column index. As @WhozCraig says above though, this is a terrible way to declare arrays of string constants.

Comment: @PaulR what happens if I don't specify the string length? What will be the maximum number of characters that I can place into each row of the array?

Comment: If you don't specify a length you could end up getting a segmentation fault,  when trying to access invalid memory.

Comment: @JasonBui: if you use the method described by WhozCraig above then you won't have to worry about explicit string lengths.

Comment: Could you let me know if you got what you were looking for from my answer. Is there anything that you would like me to clarify?

Comment: @sarcoma Sorry about the late reply! Your answer was really helpful, it covered everything that I was looking for! I tried to vote up but I could not publicly do that since I don't have enough reputation on Stack! Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: No problem, glad to help. You should be able to mark it as correct, that is if you agree that it is correct :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first set of square brackets is the number of elements in the first array, the second square bracket is the maximum length of the `char` array (string).

The second bracket in `char suits[4][9]` has nine spaces to allow space for the null character `\0` which is used to terminate the string.

So the array actually looks like this:

```
char suits[4][9] = {
    {'H', 'e', 'a', 'r', 't', 's', '\0'},
    {'D', 'i', 'a', 'm', 'o', 'n', 'd', 's', '\0'},
    {'C', 'l', 'u', 'b', 's', '\0'},
    {'S', 'p', 'a', 'd', 'e', 's', '\0'}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have :

```
char suits[4][9]
```

it means that your array has `4` rows and the `string` that will be placed in each row can have a maximum length `9` and subtracting the ending `'\0'` character, maximum length `8`.

Similarly,

```
char faces[13][6]
```

means that your array has `13` rows and the `string` that will be placed in each row can have a maximum length `6` and subtracting the ending `'\0'` character, maximum length `5`.

Comment: Sorry, I have just see that you updated you answer, you hadn't mentioned the null character when I started my answer.